# P4Python and global parameters: -d

Tags: python, python-2.7, perforce, p4python

I'm trying to create a workspace with P4 for Python. Command that works in terminal:

```
p4 -d path client -S  //stream name
```

do not work in P4 version:

```
p4.run('-d', path, 'client', '-S',  //stream, name)
```

I'm getting "[Error]: "Unknown command.  Try 'p4 help' for info."". I've also tried:

```
self.p4.protocol("-d", path)
p4.run_client('-S', //stream, name)
```

It does not produce this error but the "-d" part has no effect. I've also tried quotations, with the same result. 
Why does it not run? How to use it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you run a p4 command, the flags that come *before* the command name (the "[global options](https://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/global.options.html)") are flags to the CLI client itself, and the flags that come *after* the command are flags to the server command.

The `p4.run` function sends a command directly to the server without invoking the `p4` CLI, so the CLI options won't work (the server doesn't implement them at all so it'll just return a usage error).  If you're trying to get the effect of one of the global options, there'll be an API function that has that effect.

For example, the P4Python equivalent of `-d` is the `cwd` property:

https://www.perforce.com/manuals/p4python/Content/P4Python/python.p4.html#Instance_Attributes_..37

so instead of:

```
p4.connect()
p4.run('-d', path, 'client', '-S',  //stream, name)
```

do:

```
p4.cwd = path
p4.connect()
p4.run('client', '-S',  //stream, name)
```